# how to display and modify draftJs object in Flutter textfield to create my custom text editor app

Tags: flutter, textfield, draftjs, textspan

[image]

i need display blocks of draftJs Object like as this and modify errors when i apply my error checker on it

i use textfield to display text of every block after concatenation of it then custom text editing controller for change style according to this is image but i can't edit on text of every block , i need what's any block has been modified?